# How to parse json array that has objects with numeric key in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, json

I'm developing an ASP.NET application.
I get JSON array from the client in the following format:

`[   {"1": "value1"},   {"5": "value2"},   {"10": "value32"} ]`

I want to save this array in the database as the array of following entity:

```
class Entry
{

public int Code { get; set; }

public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

How to convert this JSON array to the array of the entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest thing is perhaps to use a Dictionary as an interim:

```
//Newtonsoft. For System.Text.Json change  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject -> JsonSerializer.Deserialize

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int,string>[]>(yourJson)
  .Select(d => Entry.FromKeyValuePair(d.First()));
```

Your Entry class will need a helper method:

```
public static Entry FromKeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp) => new Entry{ Code = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value };
```

Or you can put that logic in the Select..

The result of the Select will be an `IEnumerable<Entry>`; you can do further operations on it like `foreach`'ing it etc: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pzMrI6

It looks (from your use of an int property for Code) that you expect the key to always be ints but if they ever are not, you'll need to switch to `Dictionary<string,string>`(and the same for the key value pair in the static method) and handle parsing it yourself somehow

Answer (score 0):

You json is incorrect. It must be something like this:

```
[   {"Code":1, "Value": "value1"},   {"Code":5, "Value": "value2"},   {"Code":10, "Value": "value32"} ]
```

Then you can serialize it using the following code:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var json = "[   {\"Code\":1, \"Value\": \"value1\"},   {\"Code\":5, \"Value\": \"value2\"},   {\"Code\":10, \"Value\": \"value32\"} ]";
var test = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entry[]>(json);
Console.WriteLine(test);

internal class Entry { public int Code { get; set; } public string Value { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Why do you think the JSON is incorrect?

Comment: JSON data must be "key": "value". But this data is "value": "value"

Comment: Sometimes creators of JSON do use values as keys, alas. The JSON presented in the question is valid, even though it's more of a pain to work with for strict languages like C#, we have to remember that JSON was born out of JavaScript..

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array with a set of dictionaries.

1. Deserialize as `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.
2. Data Transformation.

   2.1 Flatten the result from *1* to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

   2.2 Cast `Dictionary<string, string>` to `List<Entry>` with assume the `key` is integer.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<Dictionary<string, string>> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
List<Entry> entries = dict
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .Select(x => new Entry
    {
        Code = Int32.Parse(x.Key),
        Value = x.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bGVsLP)

Answer (score 0):

json to class :  (use _ to make number to key)

```
 public class Root
{
    public string _1 { get; set; }
    public string _5 { get; set; }
    public string _10 { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: From json2csharp? Try using QuickType.io instead - it's a bit more sophisticated..

Comment: @CaiusJard QuickType.io not work for this json :(

Comment: Sure it will; it generates a Dictionary<string,string>, which is more reasonable than j2cs, because it's highly likely that those will not be the only 3 values ever delivered (I.e. the keys will vary and are used to transmit values)